# Handle json parse error without crashing Kafka stream processor application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streaming application which map/transforms json message and streams the output to a topic.

```
KStream<String, String> logMessageStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
logMessageStream.map((k, v) -> { //Map record 
                try { // Map record to (requestId, message)
                    // readValue throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
                    LogMessage logMessage = objectMapper.readValue(v, LogMessage.class);
                    return new KeyValue<>(logMessage.requestId(), logMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null; // <== RETURNS null due to caught exception
}).toStream().to(outoutTopic)
```

now i will get parse error if the input record json contains invalid syntax, the stream application crashes with  :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
    ....
```

I want to consume this error while mapping and continue the processing for other message. Is there any handler I can set to consumer the exception. Looking for suggestions.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also take advantage of the `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG` property, as detailed on https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-corrupted-records-and-deserialization-errors-poison-pill-records .

```java
Properties streamsSettings = new Properties();
streamsSettings.put(
  StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class.getName()
);
```

Comment: Thanks.. This provided some hint to solve my problem. I created a JsonSerde and used it while consuming the stream. So whenever there is JSON parse exception DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS will consume the exception and continue. Accepting this as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `map()` you can use `flatMap()` that allows you to return zero elements. Returning `null` from a `map()` is not allowed as pointed out in the JavaDocs:

> The provided {@link KeyValueMapper} must return a {@link KeyValue} type and must not return {@code null}.

Note, that `flatMap()` does not allow to return `null` either. But it accepts anything you can iterate over (ie, `Iterable`). For example, you can return a `Collections.singleton()` on success, and `Collection.emptySet()` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at [setUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html) method:

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);    
streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread t, Throwable e) -> {
        // your logic here
    });
```

Comment: Tried this. The handler gets invoked when exception is thrown. But it does not prevent the app from getting killed..